# Change prefix for discord bot in javascript

Tags: javascript, bots, prefix, discord

I'm making a bot and want to have a prefix to call the bot. It works to change when you don't have groups. But how do I change the prefix "!" when I use groups?

My main code

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new commando.Client();
const prefix = ":D";

bot.registry.registerGroup('random', 'Random');
bot.registry.registerCommandsIn(__dirname + "/commands");

bot.login('Botcode'
);
```

My group

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

class DiceRollCommand extends commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'roll', 
      group: 'random',
      memberName: 'roll',
      description: 'Roll a die'
    });
  }

  async run(message, args){
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    message.reply("You rolled a " + roll);
  }
}

module.exports = DiceRollCommand;
```

Comment: If you want help, we'll need code. Edit your question to include a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but

```
    const bot = new commando.Client({
    commandPrefix: ':D'
    });
```

replace line two and three with that.
You can change the :D to any prefix you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const prefix = ":D";
const bot = new commando.Client({
    commandPrefix: prefix
});

bot.registry.registerGroup('random', 'Random');
bot.registry.registerCommandsIn(__dirname + "/commands");

bot.login('Botcode'
);
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `const bot = new commando.Client({
    commandPrefix: prefix
});`
You can use a single line like this: `bot.commandPrefix = "YOUR PREFIX"`
I am not an expert so dont try and prove pros wrong with my code!

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have to edit 'client.js' in your node_module directory.
\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\client.js

This is on line 28:

```
"if(typeof options.commandPrefix === 'undefined') options.commandPrefix = 'YOUR PREFIX HERE';
```